# Recoding an age checking script so that agecheck div only shows if cookie is null

Tags: javascript, html, cookies

I am currently working on a website which requires an age check to enter. The way it is currently coded is that there is an agecheck div in the footer which displays on initial page load and remains visible until the user clicks "yes." Clicking yes sets the ofage cookie to true and it will hide the div. The problem with this is that once the user has confirmed their age, the agecheck div will randomly and periodically display for a split second when navigating between other pages/refreshing the current page.

I think the best approach to this would be to recode the script so that the agecheck div is always hidden by default and the only time it displays is if the cookie is null or the users clicks "no." My understanding of javascript and cookies is quite limited so I am looking for some guidance on this.

Here is the agecheck function:

```
function checkAge(){

  jQuery('html').css('overflow','hidden');
  jQuery('body').css('overflow','hidden');
  jQuery('body').css('height','100%');
  jQuery('html').css('height','100%');

  checkCookie();
  // check age will need to check this
  if(ofAge){
    jQuery("#ageCheck").hide();
    initPage();
  }else{
    jQuery('#ageCheckYes').click(is21);
    jQuery('#ageCheckNo').click(isNot21);
  }
};

//
// if the user is of age, animate in page
function is21(){
  setCookie();
  var  h  = jQuery(document).height();
  // animate the div off
  jQuery('#ageCheckBeerBG').animate({ top:h + 300 }, 2000+h);
  jQuery("#ageCheck").delay(900).fadeOut("fast", function() {
    initPage();
  });
}
// 
// user is not 21 send them on there way
function isNot21(){
  alert('I am sorry you must be 21 or older to enter.')
};
//
```

And here is the cookie checking code:

```
function setCookie(){
  document.cookie = "age_verified=true"
};

// check for cookie //
function checkCookie(){
  var thiscookie = getCookie("age_verified");
  if (thiscookie!="true"){
    ofAge=false;
  }else{
    ofAge=true;
  }
};
function getCookie(c_name){
  var i,x,y,ARRcookies=document.cookie.split(";");
  for (i=0;i<ARRcookies.length;i++){
    x=ARRcookies[i].substr(0,ARRcookies[i].indexOf("="));
    y=ARRcookies[i].substr(ARRcookies[i].indexOf("=")+1);
    x=x.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g,"");
    console.log(unescape(x));
    if (x==c_name){
      return unescape(y);
    };
  };
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why not just set it to be hidden using CSS (not with jQuery, in your stylesheet) and use Javascript to show it when you need it?

Comment: That's a good idea, could you point me in the right direction of how I would code a jQuery function to show the div if the agecheck cookie doesn't exist(or exists as false)? Thanks!

Comment: just include it in the cookie checking code you already have written.  see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CSS in your stylesheet to set the element as hidden by default.  Where you set ofAge to true/false, if it is set to false, then show it.